# Google Maps leaking JNI global reference

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin.Android app using Google Maps in various scenarios - user can for example open details of various paths displayed as polylines on map. From time to time I get this error:

```
E/dalvikvm(13160): JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)

W/dalvikvm(13160): JNI global reference table (0x848a2008) dump:

W/dalvikvm(13160):   Last 10 entries (of 51200):

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51199: 0x45a244d0 com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51198: 0x45e5e9d8 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51197: 0x45e5ea18 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51196: 0x45e5ea58 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51195: 0x45e5ead8 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.VisibleRegion

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51194: 0x45f9bc28 com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51193: 0x43975690 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51192: 0x43975788 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51191: 0x439757a8 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds

W/dalvikvm(13160):     51190: 0x43975810 com.google.android.gms.maps.model.VisibleRegion
```

Followed by summary of global reference table. Biggest items are always :

```
1668 of com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng (1668 unique instances)
...
378 of com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline (378 unique instances)
...
44439 of com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h (44439 unique instances)
```

I know that Xamarin use Managed Callable Wrappers for LatLng, Polyline and all this stuff, so I already added disposing logic around these. But what about the real killer:

> com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h

I have no idea what this is (google is not helping), how to dispose of it and thus prevent gref table overflow from killing my app. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no trace of cleacut.a.h in Google API. Are you using any external libraries with custom native code? Look at the bottom of this article: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/refs.html. I guess you can try deleting this reference locally.

Comment: Nope, no external libraries, just Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps